# javascript regex for finding text several lines before the match

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I am trying to create a regex that finds text in a markdown file. Basically, I have "tasks" marked with the `- [ ]` or `- [x]` characters (undone or done) and project headers (marked with `##`). I would like to find all undone tasks and their project names.

For example, for this sample text:

```
# Top of File

## Project A
Descriptive line

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus elit non nibh lobortis molestie.

- [ ] an undone task
- [x] a completed task
- [x] second completed task

## Project B
Descriptive line

- [x] a completed task
- [ ] an uncompleted task

## Project C
Descriptive line

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus elit non nibh lobortis molestie.

- [x] completed task
- [ ] uncompleted task
- [x] completed task
```

I would like to return:

Project A, an undone task
Project B, an uncompleted task
Project C, uncompleted task

This maybe gets close, but I will have variable amounts of tasks and the regex wants to know how many lines to look ahead, and it's too variable. `((.*(\n|\r|\r\n)){5})\- \[ \]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `match()` here to alternatively find the project or incomplete lines.  Then, do a reduction to combine the two matching lines by a comma separator.

```js
var input = `# Top of File

## Project A
Descriptive line

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus elit non nibh lobortis molestie.

- [ ] an undone task
- [x] a completed task
- [x] second completed task

## Project B
Descriptive line

- [x] a completed task
- [ ] an uncompleted task

## Project C
Descriptive line

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus elit non nibh lobortis molestie.

- [x] completed task
- [ ] uncompleted task
- [x] completed task`;

var lines = input.match(/## (.*)|- \[ \] (.*)/g)
                 .map(x => x.match(/\w+(?: \w+)*/g)[0]);
var output = [];
var i=0;
while (i < lines.length) {
    output.push(lines[i] + ", " + lines[i+1]);
    i += 2;
}

console.log(output);
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used to find the matching lines:

- `## (.*)` match and capture the project text
- `|` OR
- `- \[ \] (.*)` match and capture the incomplete text

But the `match()` function will return the leading portion (e.g. `##`) which we don't want.  So I added a `map()` step which removes this leading content.  Finally, we iterate the array of lines and combine in order with a comma.